# How to initialize const in a struct in C (with malloc)

Tags: c, struct, initialization, malloc, constants

I have tried;

```
void *malloc(unsigned int);
struct deneme {
    const int a = 15;
    const int b = 16;
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    struct deneme *mydeneme = malloc(sizeof(struct deneme));
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the compiler's error:

```
gereksiz.c:3:17: error: expected ':', ',', ';', '}' or '__attribute__' before '=' token
```

And, also this;

```
void *malloc(unsigned int);
struct deneme {
    const int a;
    const int b;
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    struct deneme *mydeneme = malloc(sizeof(struct deneme));
    mydeneme->a = 15;
    mydeneme->b = 20;
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the compiler's error:

```
gereksiz.c:10:5: error: assignment of read-only member 'a'
gereksiz.c:11:5: error: assignment of read-only member 'b'
```

And neither got compiled. Is there any way to initialize a const variable inside a struct when allocation memory with malloc?

Comment: You have to cast away constness: `*(int*)(&mydeneme->a)=15;`

Comment: The call to `malloc` causes undefined behaviour as the prototype is incompatible with the library function which is `void *malloc(size_t);`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You need to cast away the const to initialize the fields of a malloc'ed structure:

```
struct deneme *mydeneme = malloc(sizeof(struct deneme));
*(int *)&mydeneme->a = 15;
*(int *)&mydeneme->b = 20;
```

Alternately, you can create an initialized version of the struct and memcpy it:

```
struct deneme deneme_init = { 15, 20 };
struct deneme *mydeneme = malloc(sizeof(struct deneme));
memcpy(mydeneme, &deneme_init, sizeof(struct deneme));
```

You can make `deneme_init` static and/or global if you do this a lot (so it only needs to be built once).

---

Explanation of why this code is not undefined behaviour as suggested by some of the comments, using C11 standard references:

- This code does not violate 6.7.3/6 because the space returned by `malloc` is not "an object **defined** with a const-qualified type".  The expression `mydeneme->a` is not an object, it is an expression. Although it has `const`-qualified type, it denotes an object which was not defined with a const-qualified type (in fact, not defined with any type at all).
- The strict aliasing rule is never violated by writing into space allocated by `malloc`, because the *effective type* (6.5/6) is updated by each write.

(The strict aliasing rule can be violated by reading from space allocated by `malloc` however).

In Chris's code samples, the first one sets the effective type of the integer values to `int`, and the second one sets the effective type to `const int`, however in both cases going on to read those values through `*mydeneme` is correct because the strict-aliasing rule (6.5/7 bullet 2) permits reading an object through an expression which is equally or more qualified than the effective type of the object. Since the expression `mydeneme->a` has type `const int`, it can be used to read objects of effective type `int` and `const int`.

Comment: Isn't the const-cast access undefined behaviour?

Comment: No -- const cast is well defined if the memory in question is not const (such as what comes back from malloc).  It only undefined if you try to modify a const object via the cast.

Comment: No it's defined, it just means that programmer takes responsibility and knows what is he(sorry ladies) doing.
My teacher use to say that one can easily shoot into his leg thought.

Comment: Standard says: (6.7.3) If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type, the behavior is undefined. and in undefined behaviour section: An attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type (6.7.3). That would make this example exhibit ub.

Comment: @self.: But there is no object defined with a const-qualified type here -- the object is allocated with malloc (which is never const) and then converted to a const type.  So the cast is just casting away a const that was applied by a previous (implicit) cast (of the return value from malloc), and the object itself is not const.

Comment: *But there is no object defined with a const-qualified type here* Why the cast then. Actually it is like this; When you point `mydeneme` to some memory, its element `a` and `b` become const qualified, in the next line you try to change that by casting, violating the rules( and strict aliasing too, but that is not that important since standard explicitly forbids modifying const objects ).

Comment: Casting something to a const type does not make the object const.  The only way to get a const object is to *define* the object with a const type.  Since the object is defined by malloc here it is not const.

Comment: No object is not defined by malloc. Objects in the case of allocated storage are defined by their effective type. 6.5(6) When you access an object trough an lvalue, the effective type is set to lvalue type. Object in this cast has elements with const qualifiers.

Comment: The lvalue in the access is `*(int *)&mydename->a`, which is not const.

Comment: Standard is crystal clear on the subject; you are creating undefined behaviour: `mydename->a` is of type `const int`; *(6.7.3) If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type*  which you manage to reenact here: `*(int *)&mydeneme->a = 15;` then the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54309/discussion-between-chris-dodd-and-self).

Comment: @ChrisDodd: I do not have enough insight on C / compiler internals. According to [securecoding.cert.org - C EXP05-EX3](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/EXP05-C.+Do+not+cast+away+a+const+qualification) would you say, one could cast away the `const` qualifier from statically allocated structs also?   **EXP05-EX3:** _Because const means "read-only," and not "constant," it is sometimes useful to declare struct members as (pointer to) const objects ... . Within those functions, however, it may be necessary to strip off the const qualification to update those members._

Comment: @Florian: In the case of a statically (or stack/auto) allocated object, the object *is* defined with const type (since the declaration defines the object), so casting away const does result in undefined behavior.   You can instead initialize the object with a `{`..`}` initializer to avoid the problem.

Comment: @ChrisDodd I'm afraid, not 100% sure what you propose: An empty initialization like `struct someData sdInstance0 = {};` || sole definition like `struct SomeData sdInstance0, sdInstance1;` (of which the latter should already reserve space on the stack - am I correct? At least that works on TI ARM compiler 5.2.5)

Comment: @Florian: I mean like the initialization of `deneme_init` in my second example above.  That's the only legal way to initialize const fields in a local or global (non-dynamic) object with const fields.

Comment: +1 The habituated cognition needed to easily/fluidly rigorously mentally verify correctness of code like this is certainly non-negligible, and it is liable to nuance decay (the nuance that this is only correct because the memory was dynamically allocated is not forced as part of the mechanism of achieving it to be explicit in the code, and so people are liable to learn-by-example in a way wrongly generalized to non-dynamically allocated objects) but it seems correct, and a `memcpy` approach would have the same downsides anyway. Very nice.

Answer (score 11):

Have you tried to do like this:

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    struct deneme mydeneme = { 15, 20 };
    struct deneme *pmydeneme = malloc(sizeof(struct deneme));
    memcpy(pmydeneme, &mydeneme , sizeof(mydeneme));
    return 0;
}
```

I have not tested but the code seems correct

Comment: You can't really prove if something is undefined behavior or not by "the code seems correct". In this case the code is actually correct, but the only way to tell is to read up what the standard says. You can't prove it with trial & error.

Comment: @Lundin: The Standard was written on the presumption that because the easiest way for an implementation which does everything that is mandated would also accommodate many other useful things not mandated by the Standard, and because the market would drive support for such "popular extensions", there was no need for the Standard to exhaustively list them all.  As such, the only thing that should be affected by the Standard's failure to list a particular useful corner case would be whether or not programs relying upon the case may be termed "strictly conforming".

Comment: @supercat But people also have a habit to post code on SO that does explicitly violate listed UB or "shall"/constraints of the standard, then argue that it "seems to be working". Every historical event of catastrophic failures caused by software had software that "seemed to be working" too.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting I found this C99 way is working in clang but not in gcc

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    struct deneme *pmydeneme = malloc(sizeof(struct deneme));
    *pmydeneme = (struct deneme) {15, 20};
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @NathanTuggy it looks like an answer to me

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Perhaps so; the "doesn't work in gcc" mention threw me off.

Comment: After further checking... this code is incorrect. `*pmydeneme` is **not** a *modifiable lvalue* (C11 6.3.2/1) because it is a struct with a const-qualified member. The assignment operator (6.5.16/2) requires a modifiable lvalue as the left operand.  If clang accepts it  then it is a bug in clang.

Comment: Replace the line that starts with an asterisk to `struct deneme temp = {15,20}; memcpy(pmydeneme, &temp, sizeof temp);` and the code should have defined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on the answer by @Chris Dodd, I've been reading through the "language-lawyer" details of the standard and it appears that this code is well-defined:

```
struct deneme deneme_init = { 15, 20 };
struct deneme *mydeneme = malloc(sizeof(struct deneme));
memcpy(mydeneme, &deneme_init, sizeof(struct deneme));
```

Alternatively, to dynamically create a complete struct object that's const qualified:

```
const struct deneme deneme_init = { 15, 20 };
struct deneme *mydeneme = malloc(sizeof(struct deneme));
memcpy(mydeneme, &deneme_init, sizeof(struct deneme));

const struct deneme *read_only = mydeneme;
```

---

Rationale:

The first thing one needs to establish when getting to the bottom of this, is if a so-called *lvalue* has a type and if so, does that type come with qualifiers or not. This is defined in C11 6.3.2.1/1:

> An *lvalue* is an expression (with an object type other than void) that potentially
> designates an object; if an lvalue does not designate an object when it is evaluated, the behavior is undefined. When an object is said to have a particular type, the type is specified by the lvalue used to designate the object. A *modifiable lvalue* is an lvalue that does not have array type, does not have an incomplete type, does not have a constqualified type, and if it is a structure or union, does not have any member (including, recursively, any member or element of all contained aggregates or unions) with a constqualified type.

So clearly a lvalue does not only have a type, but also qualifiers. It is not a modifiable lvalue if it is const-qualified or if it is a struct with const-qualified members.

Moving on to the rules of "strict aliasing" and *effective type*, C11 6.5/7:

> The *effective type* of an object for an access to its stored value is the declared type of the object, if any.<sup>87)</sup> If a value is stored into an object having no declared type through an
> lvalue having a type that is not a character type, then the type of the lvalue becomes the
> effective type of the object for that access and for subsequent accesses that do not modify
> the stored value. If a value is copied into an object having no declared type using
> `memcpy` or `memmove`, or is copied as an array of character type, then the effective type
> of the modified object for that access and for subsequent accesses that do not modify the
> value is the effective type of the object from which the value is copied, if it has one. For
> all other accesses to an object having no declared type, the effective type of the object is
> simply the type of the lvalue used for the access.

> 87. Allocated objects have no declared type.

This means that the allocated chunk returned by malloc has no effective type until something is stored inside that memory location through a lvalue write access, either through assignment or `memcpy`. It then gets the effective type of the lvalue used in that write access.

Notably, the type of the pointer pointing at that memory location is completely irrelevant. It might as well have been a `volatile bananas_t*` since it isn't used to access the lvalue (at least not yet). ***Only the type used for lvalue access matters.***

Now this is where it gets fuzzy: it might matter if this write access is done through a modifiable lvalue or not. The rule of effective type above doesn't mention qualifiers and the "strict aliasing rule" as such doesn't care about if an object is qualified or not ("*type*" may alias "*qualified type*" and vice versa).

But there are other cases where it might matter if the effective type is read-only or not: most notably if we later attempt to do a non-qualified lvalue access to an object which effective type is const-qualified. (C11 6.7.3/6 "If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type, the behavior is undefined.") From the previously quoted part above lvalues, it *makes sense* for effective type to have a qualifier, even if the standard doesn't mention that explicitly.

Therefore to be absolutely sure, we have to get the type used for the lvalue access right. If the whole object is meant to be read-only, then the second snippet on top of this post should be used. Otherwise, if it is read/write (but potentially with qualified members), the first snippet should be used. Then it can never go wrong no matter how you read the standard.

Comment: Operations that would overwrite the value of an object without a declared type will erase any pre-existing Effective Type it may have had.

Comment: @supercat Yes but once it has an effective type, subsequent lvalue writes by different types would likely be a strict aliasing violation.

Comment: From 6.5p6, "If a value is stored into an object having no declared type through an lvalue having a type that is not a character type, then the type of the lvalue becomes the effective type of the object for that access and for subsequent accesses *that do not modify the stored value*."  The rule as written leads to unworkable corner cases which neither clang nor gcc handle correctly, but a defect report suggestion that the italicized text be stricken was refused.  A properly written rule should base the persistence of "effective type" on the existence of pointers that will be used...

Comment: ...to access the storage as their current type, so that if e.g. the only extant pointer to an object gets converted to `void*` and stored in a pool, there would be no reason to care about what types had previously been used to access the storage, even if some bytes get read before they're next written (e.g. because they're part of a partially-written structure) but in any case any const-qualified Effective Type that might be held by storage without a declared type would be erased by the next operation that would modify it, just as would any other Effective Type.

Comment: @supercat It is what it is. C has numerous serious flaws, this is just one of many. All the various hiccups and corner cases related to strict aliasing is exactly why we should avoid any attempt to change the type of a stored object, when possible. It's only possible to work professionally with C in general if you adopt a safe subset and ban various language features from use.

Comment: Clang and gcc will work correctly with optimizations disabled.  Enabling optimizations makes them unreliable even in cases which are fully defined by the Standard.  While it may sometimes be necessary to work around the bugs or limitations of certain compilers, the programming community would be much better off if the makers of clang and gcc would support a mode that does peephole optimizations and register-caching optimizations, but which flushes registers around "tricky" constructs and refrains from unsound assumptions, rather than making the only reliable mode `-O0`.

Comment: Perhaps the best approach might be to have a macro which on clang or gcc would be defined as a memory-clobbering `asm` directive, but on other compilers may expand so something else or be empty, and then use that directive anyplace that clang or gcc might otherwise mess things up.  Compilers that aren't being deliberately evil should treat memory clobbers as a barrier to any aliasing-based inferences involving accesses on opposite sides, and trying to armor code against deliberately-evil compilers would be a fool's errand.

Comment: Even with `-fno-strict-aliasing`, clang and gcc are prone to make unsound optimizations, some of which break behaviors that are defined by the Standard, and some of which break constructs which couldn't be expressed "portably", but which work with optimizations disabled, whose behavior could be defined based upon how an implementation chooses to define "implementation-defined" aspects of `volatile`, and which compilers should be configurable to regard as "potentially tricky" without affecting the performance of most normal code.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with **Christ Dodd**'s answer, since I think his solution gives *Undefined Behaviour* according to the standards, as others said.

To "work-around" the `const` qualifier in a way that does not invoke undefined behaviour, I propose the following solution:

1. Define a `void*` variable initialized with a `malloc()` call.
2. Define and object of the desired type, in this case `struct deneme` and initialize it in some way that `const` qualifier does not complain (that is, in the declaration-line itself).
3. Use `memcpy()` to copy the bits of the `struct deneme` object to the `void*` object.
4. Declare a pointer to `struct deneme` object and initialize it to the `(void*)` variable, previously cast to `(struct deneme *)`.

So, my code would be:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
struct deneme {
    const int a;
    const int b;
};
struct deneme* deneme_init(struct deneme data) {
    void *x = malloc(sizeof(struct deneme));
    memcpy(x, &data, sizeof(struct deneme));
    return (struct deneme*) x;
}
int main(void) {
    struct deneme *obj = deneme_init((struct deneme) { 15, 20, } );
    printf("obj->a: %d, obj->b: %d.\n", obj->a, obj->b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This isn't any different from the example posted by Chris Dodd. The type of the pointer doesn't matter the slightest, only the lvalue access type matters. In this case the type that `&data` points at.

Comment: The dynamic storage data pointed by a pointer do not automagically gain new type just because the pointer is cast (implicitly or not). The effective type is set the object is written to with assignment or `memcpy`.

Answer (score 0):

The Standard uses the `const` keyword as a weird hybrid between an lvalue qualifier and a storage class, but doesn't make clear which meaning is applicable to struct members.

If one has a structure `s` of type `struct S` with member `m` of type `T`, the construct `s.foo` takes an lvalue of type `struct S` and derives from it an lvalue of type `T`.  If `T` contains a qualifier, that modifier will affect the lvalue thus produced.

The Standard certainly recognizes the possibility that code may take an lvalue which is not `const`-qualified, derive from that an lvalue that is `const`-qualified, derive from that one which--like the original--is not, and then use the latter lvalue to modify the object.  What is unclear is whether the use of a `const` modifier on a struct member affects the underlying storage class of an object, or whether it would merely cause a `const` modifier to be applied to any lvalue formed using the member-access operator.  I think the latter interpretation makes a lot more sense, since the former leads to many ambiguous and unworkable corner cases, but I don't think the Standard makes clear which interpretation is supposed to apply.  Since all situations whose behavior would be defined under the former interpretation would be defined identically under the latter, I see no reason the authors of the Standard wouldn't have regarded the latter interpretation as superior, but they might have wanted to leave open the possibility that in some cases, on some implementations, the former interpretation might offer some advantage implementation the Committee hadn't foreseen.