# How to manipulate an array of structs with const members

Tags: c, struct, constants

I'm trying to understand how 'const' works in C.
What I would like to create is a `polygon struct` whose members cannot be mutated.

I started by creating the following structs

```
struct vector2{
    float x;
    float y;
};

struct polygon2{
    const size_t count;
    struct vector2* const points;
};
```

To create a polygon I created the following function:

```
struct polygon2* polygon2_create(size_t count)
{
    struct vector2* points = calloc(count, sizeof *points);
    struct polygon2 temp = {.count = count,
                            .points = points};
    struct polygon2* actual = malloc(sizeof *actual);
    memcpy(actual, &temp, sizeof(*actual));

    return actual;
}
```

[I believe this function doesn't cause undefined behavior.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9691556/1642116)

This way I can do things like

```
struct polygon2* poly = polygon2_create(30);
poly->points[3] = (struct vector2){7.1, 5.3};
```

But I can't do

```
poly->points = NULL;
```

Nor

```
poly->count = 3;
```

Which is great. I'm sure that I won't accidentally change the contents of `struct polygon`.

But I'd like to make `vector2`'s members const too.
If I change `vector2` to:

```
struct vector2{
    const float x;
    const float y;
};
```

I no longer am able to do this:

```
poly->points[3] = (struct vector2){7.1, 5.3};
```

I'd like to know why. I expected that making vector2's members const I wouldn't be able to do this

```
poly->points[3].x = 3
```

But I'd still be able to do this

```
poly->points = otherpoint;
```

Can someone explain what am I missing? And how can I achieve the following:

- create a "immutable" `vector2 struct`
- create a `polygon struct` whose `points` or `count` member can't be changed, but the things pointed by `points` can be 'swaped'.

Comment: const stands for constant value.a.k.a a value that a variable that cannot have its value changed. For example, this : `const int x=1;x=2;` will give an error. In my gcc version, the error will be `assignment of read-only variable x`.

Comment: You can't make a dynamically-allocated structure immutable, because you have to modify it to assign the initial values after allocating it.

Comment: @Mike: This is wrong! C does not have symbolic constants, except _enum-constants_. `const` qualified objects are still variables, but the programmer guarantees not to change them, i.e. the value **will** not change. It very well **can** change if the programmer breaks this contract, resulting in undefined behaviour. The diagnostics by the compiler is kind of courtesy, but not guaranteed, e.g. if you cast away the `const` or use pointers (there are scenarios the compiler will not detect such cases even without a cast).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const` qualification of a type means that lvalue expressions of that type are not modifiable.  In particular, lvalues of `const` type or of composite type with at least one `const` member, recursively, cannot be the left-hand side of an assignment operator, and pointers to such objects cannot be `free()`d.

Moreover, qualified, including `const`-qualified, types are different types from their unqualified counterparts and from differently-qualified versions of the underlying unqualifed type.  This has implications on compatibility of composite types that have qualified members.

On the other hand, do not mistake `const` to be a promise that the value is actually constant.  It can be the case that the same object can designated by multiple lvalues, some `const` and others non-`const`.  In that case, the object can be modified via any of the non-`const` lvalues that designate it, and those modifications will be visible even via the `const` lvalues that designate it.

With respect to the specifics of your question:

- I agree that your function `polygon2_create()` is valid and has well-defined behavior.  In particular, `const` members of a struct can be initialized in an initializer, and functions such as `memcpy()` can modify memory in which an object that can be referenced via a `const` lvalue is stored.  Your compiler might warn about the `memcpy()`, though.
- More generally, the initialization and assignment behavior and constraints you describe are correct.
- As for `poly->points[3] = (struct vector2){7.1, 5.3};`, how would it make sense for that to be acceptable if the members of `struct vector2` were `const`?  If allowed, the assignment certainly would modify them, and preventing that is exactly the point of `const`.  Or if you prefer a citation to authority, C2011 6.3.2.1/1 specifies that if a structure type has any `const` members, then lvalue expressions of that type are not modifiable.

It sounds like you are confused about the semantics of whole-struct assignment.  If you assign one struct to a different struct, you are not replacing one struct with the other; rather you are copying the *value* of one struct to the other.  This is exactly analogous to assignments to simple types, such as `int`.

You asked,

> how can I achieve the following:
>
> - create a "immutable" vector2 struct

You already know how to do this, to the extent that it is possible.  If you make all the members `const` then they cannot be modified via an expression of type `struct vector2`.  As I remarked before, however, this does not confer absolute immutability.  C has no such thing.

> - create a polygon struct whose points or count member can't be changed, but the things pointed by points can be 'swaped'.

I'm not sure I understand how an ability to swap points is consistent with your desired level of unmodifiability.  Certainly, if `struct vector2` has `const` members then you cannot assign to lvalue expressions of that type.  You could still perform swapping via `memcpy()`, though, or by casting to a modifiable type.  These mechanisms do, however, violate at least the spirit of `const`-ness.  Your compiler will likely warn about them.

You could consider changing `points` from a `struct vector2 * const` to a `struct vector2 ** const`.  You can then swap the (non-`const`) `struct vector *` objects accessible via `*points`:

```
struct vector *temp = poly->points[3];
poly->points[3] = poly->points[2];
poly->points[2] = temp;
```

Your focus on immutability makes me wonder whether you come from a Java background; either way, that's more Java-esque, since all non-primitives in Java are references, which are more or less pointers.

Overall, however, I think you are overly focused on immutability.  `const`-ness will cause you trouble, especially with memory management.  Consider doing without, at least for your struct members themselves.  At most, use `const` qualification on function parameter types to express that the function will not modify the actual argument, and perhaps on global variables where you want at least to be warned about any possibility that they will be modified.

Comment: Very thorough answer, thank you. I actually dislike Java.  My preference for immutability comes from a functional background. Pure functions and immutable objects not only are beautiful, but easier to reason about, imo.