# `char * const` field considered "incompatible with C" by MSVC (VS2015)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, struct, extern

I have the following code which compiles without warnings in VS2015 (all warnings enabled):

```
// buffer.h

typedef struct {
    char * const start; // start of the buffer
    char * const end;   // one byte after the end of the buffer
    char * pos;         // current position
} Buffer;

static inline Buffer Buffer_create(char *buffer, int size) {
    Buffer b;

    char ** const startPtr = &((char *)b.start);
    char ** const endPtr = &((char *)b.end);

    *startPtr = buffer;
    *endPtr = buffer + size;
    b.pos = buffer;

    return b;
}
```

Since `.start` and `.end` members are `const`, I am doing the casting thingy to avoid getting compile warnings, and the code indeed compiles without warnings and works without issues.

However, if I want to test this using gtest, and if I want to reference this file from a .cpp file:

```
// some_file.cpp

extern "C" {
    #include "buffer.h"
}
```

I get the the [C4190 warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4190) from Visual Studio, described as:

> 'Buffer_create' has C-linkage specified, but returns UDT 'Buffer' which is incompatible with C

But the UDT is clearly "compatible with C", since I can build it without warnings until I try to reference it from a cpp file.

**If I remove `const` from the `struct` definition, the warning goes away.**

So, it seems like MSVC thinks `char * const` is not "compatible with C". Am I doing something illegal, or is this a compiler bug?

Comment: `&((char *)b.start);` is an error. You cannot use the `&` operator on an rvalue.  (MSVC has an extension that a cast to the same type can be an lvalue, the other problems you experience perhaps cascade from this)

Comment: If you have to do that casting, has it not occurred to you that there is something very basic wrong with your code?

Comment: @M.M: but what is the "proper" way of instantiating a `char * const` field then? The extension you are referring to was producing a "non-standard extension" warning, so I switched to a rvalue to get rid of the warning.

Comment: Also your code (even if it compiled) would modify a const object, which is undefined behaviour

Comment: @Lou - Give `b` a proper initializer. Anything in scope can be used in it.

Comment: @Lou an initializer is the proper way. `Buffer b = { buffer, buffer + size, buffer };`

Comment: I guess you mean "initializing", not "instantiating".  you can initialize using the syntax for initialization.  I would recommend you simply not use a struct with const members, they're more trouble than they are worth

Comment: Crap, I am sorry, this is probably an XY problem then. I wasn't aware that simply using C99 initializers would solve the issue.

Comment: That initialization syntax has been in C and C++ since before standardization

Comment: I also would not recommend using an `inline` function in a header intended to be included from both C and C++,  it's outside the purview of standards and asking for trouble.  `inline` has different semantics in C than in C++. Also,  the warning message you got suggests that the compiler might not even support language-mixing for functions that return a struct  by value

Comment: @M.M: right, designated initializers are C99, but a non-constant initializer also throws a "nonstandard extension" warning.

Comment: Never use a cast just to silence the compiler **unless you really know what you are doing**.

Comment: @Olaf: that would be a good tip, if there was any other way to assign these fields in MSVC without warnings.

Comment: @Lou: If you can't, there is something else wrong with your code! As you wrote: XY problem. As a sidenote: C is not a subset of C++, it is a different language. Compiling C code with a C++ compiler is often doomed for non-trivial, well written code..

Comment: @Olaf: my point is: there doesn't seem to be any single way, apart from the "cast" above, to **assign a const pointer struct field in MSVC**. The casting part does not produce a warning and is not even related to my question, but if you want, throw everything else a way and try to assign it.

Comment: @Lou: There very well is. Just get the types and qualifiers correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation you linked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4190) for warning C4190,  it is not supported to have a function which returns a `struct` by value, called from both C and C++.

(In the C++ Standard most of the details of language-mixing are given as implementation-defined, and in this case MSVC complies by documenting that this is not supported).

I also would not recommend having an `inline` function in a header that is compiled as both C and C++, because the semantics of `inline` differs between the two languages so it is asking for trouble.

You will have to make a major design change to avoid this problem, if you want to use `Buffer_create` from both languages. For example, "return" the result via a pointer out-parameter, and do away with the `const` struct members.

Comment: Well, I guess I'll just remove `const` then. Removing `inline` and separating the function into two `.h`/`.c` files didn't solve any warnings, and switching to a different testing framework would be a pain right now.

Comment: Btw, regarding your first comment on my question: "`&((char *)b.start);` is an error. You cannot use the `&` operator on an rvalue." - is this from the C standard? Because this part compiles with zero warnings (with `/Wall` flag). How does this differ from, say, `&buffer[5]` (which I often encounter)?

Comment: Yes it's from the C Standard. MSVC has a non-standard extension that using a cast to the same type yields an lvalue. I conjecture that it also applies this extension if casting to a type which would be the same apart from your cast. Have you tried disabling MS extensions (I think it is `/Za`) ?

Comment: `buffer[5]` is an lvalue; the rest of a cast is not an lvalue

Comment: Ok, sorry for disturbing you again, so if I had written `char** startPtr = ((char**)&b.start)` instead, then if would have been ok? According to this answer: [How to initialize const in a struct in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9691556/1488067).

Comment: That line is OK but it would be undefined behaviour when you go on to write `*startPtr =` because you are assigning to a const object.  The answer you link to is different to your case and this is explained why in the bullet points in that answer.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure about the structure definition? It does not make much sense to define the members as `const`, but rather the pointers as `const char *` or `char const *` which is equivalent:

```
typedef struct {
    char const *start; // start of the buffer
    char const *end;   // one byte after the end of the buffer
    char * pos;        // current position
} Buffer;
```

Try this definition in both C and C++ contexts.

If your intend is to have constant pointers in the structure, you could use an initializer in the `Buffer_create` function instead of these ugly casts:

```
static inline Buffer Buffer_create(char *buffer, int size) {
    Buffer b = { buffer, buffer + size, buffer };
    return b;
}
```

Comment: I guess the goal is that the pointers never change, not that they point to some const data.

Comment: Of course that's what it means, but maybe not what the OP intended.

Comment: As Felix wrote, it's not that the data won't change, it's just a "bounded buffer" UDT which has some functions for appending data to it. It's just to make sure only `pos` will change, while `pos` can be moved around and dereferenced.

Comment: Thanks, although the initializer again throws a "nonstandard extension" warning in MSVC. The only way it didn't throw any warnings (when accessed through C code) was through the ugly casts. :) I made a (perhaps stupid) decision to try to make `start` and `end` const pointers, which was supposed to give me some additional safety, but it all went to pieces when I wrote the first unit test in gtest.

Comment: @Lou: I guess the easy path is to give up fighting the MSVC compiler and drop the `const` keyword. Or maybe use a `#define` to only have it in the C version.