# Interface with const buffers, but implementation requiring non-const buffers

Tags: c

I have an interface like the following:

```
typedef void (*message_destructor)(void *buffer);
typedef struct message_t {
    void *buffer;
    size_t sz;
    message_destructor dtor;
} message_t;

void message_free(message_t *msg);
void message_dispatcher(message_t *msg);

typedef void (*message_consume_t)(const message_t *msg);
```

The implementation would be something like the following (this is a simplification):

```
struct {
    message_consume_t cb;
} all_consummers[10];

void message_dispatcher(message_t *msg)
{
    for (i=0;i<10;++i) {
        all_consumers[i]->cb(msg);
    }
    message_free(msg);
}

void message_free(message_t *msg) {
    if (msg->dtor)
        msg->dtor(msg->buffer);
    free(msg);
}
```

In short, the message can be created in several ways, from different threads, etc... and they are passed to the `message_dispatcher` in order to send it across the different modules of the system. Afterwards, the `message_dispatcher` frees the message.

It is absolutely required that no consumer modifies in any way the message, otherwise it would modify the data for the next consumers.

But despite being the message parameter declared as `const`, each consumer still can modify the buffer, since it is non-const, because the implementation requires it to be non-const in order to be able to destroy / free it. Also the producers have to be able to modify it, in order to create the message.

Is there any way to declare such a restriction in plain C, without changing the client code? I.e., without having to change all the appearances of `buffer` in all the consumers.

---

It would be nice if there could be something like two interfaces, one directed to the producers and the implementation, where the buffer is non-const, and one directed to the consumers, where the buffer is const.

---

Edit: I am thinking on using the following approach:

```
typedef struct message_t {
    union {
        const void *buffer;
        struct {
            void *buffer;
        } _p;
    };
    size_t sz;
    message_destructor dtor;
} message_t;
```

This way, the client code accessing buffer will always see it as `const void*`, while the producer code would use `_p.buffer`, which is non-const.

This solution in the end is similar to the solution proposed by Lundin, but using only one struct instead of two.

Now my concern is, would be this undefined behaviour?

Comment: It is valid to cast the `const` from a pointer target away (an use such a resulting non-const pointer for modifications on the target) as long as the target's memory wasn't declared `const` to begin with.

Comment: @PSkocik yes, I had thought about it, but I am not confortable casting away the `const` in the free function, when the construction of the object does not happen in the library, but comes from different parts of the system already constructed. Is like I would like to have two different interfaces, one for producers (and destruction) and one for consumers

Comment: `Is there any way to declare such a restriction in plain C` You can _always_ cast the const away.

Comment: @KamilCuk You can always do the pointer conversion itself, but a lvalue write access with type `x` to an object of type `const x` would invoke undefined behavior (6.7.3/6).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as undefined behavior is concerned, const-ness is a property of the memory/object. This means that as long as an object wasn't declared const, it's OK to use either const or non-const pointers to it.

To accomplish your goal, mark `buffer` and `sz` const, then modify `message_free` to cast away the const:

```c
typedef struct message_t {
    const void *buffer;
    const size_t sz;
    message_destructor dtor;
} message_t;

void message_free(message_t *msg) {
    if (msg->dtor)
        msg->dtor((void*)msg->buffer);
    free(msg);
}
```

And make sure that underlying memory of `buffer` is always non-const. This is always the case with `malloc`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9691556/3208723).

I'd add something like this to ensure the memory comes from `malloc`:

```c
message_t *message_alloc(size_t bufsize) {
    message_t *msg = malloc(sizeof *msg);
    msg->buffer = malloc(bufsize);
    *(size_t*)&msg->sz = bufsize;
    return msg;
}
```

Now without an explicit cast, the compiler will at least warn about unwanted mutations:

```
void message_consumer(const message_t* msg) {
    msg->sz = 5; // error
    int x = 5;
    msg->buffer = &x; // error
    char * mutable_buffer = msg->buffer; // warning
    ((char*)msg->buffer)[0] = 5; // no error/warning
}
```

[Full godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/ef5boW).

Comment: Ok, I guess this is the best solution. About your "no error" case, it does not matter too much, since we try to avoid castings. When using a void buffer, we use intermediate variables with the desired type. The assignemnt does not need to be casted, thus the compiler is able to detect the const-ness mistake. I will wait a bit more to see if anybody has a different answer. If no, I will accept this one

Comment: That's a good point. I'll update the answer to mention that.

Comment: Is there any need to declare the `sz` member `const` since none of the other members of `message_t` are declared `const`?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a `const` qualified version where needed. That is, define two different struct types:

```
typedef void msg_destructor_t (void *buffer);

typedef struct {
    void *buffer;
    size_t sz;
    msg_destructor_t* dtor;
} msg_t;

typedef struct {
    const void *buffer;
    size_t sz;
    msg_destructor_t* dtor;
} msg_ro_t;  // read only version

typedef void msg_consume_t (const msg_ro_t *msg);
```

You'd then get this:

```
struct {
    msg_consume_t* cb;
} all_consumers[10];

void msg_free (msg_t *msg) {
    if (msg->dtor)
        msg->dtor(msg->buffer);
    free(msg);
}

void msg_dispatcher (msg_t *msg)
{
    for (size_t i=0;i<10;++i) {
        all_consumers[i].cb((const msg_ro_t*)msg);
    }
    msg_free(msg);
}
```

This blocks read/write access for the consumers, who only have access to the `msg_ro_t` struct. The pointer conversions are safe since `void*` and `const void*` pointer types alias.

(Or well, the C pointer aliasing rules are pretty shaky and ambiguous, but if you read them by the letter, then if the actual object is declared as `msg_t` having `void*` as the effective type of the first member, then you can access that member either through a `const` qualified `void*` or through a `struct` containing such a member (6.5/7).)

Comment: I like this approach. The problem is that both structs should be kept in sync. Could it be done using some sort of unions and structs between both types, so the non-const is hidden behind an additional field? Like the following: `typedef struct { union {const void *buffer; struct {void *buffer}p;};size_t sz; msg_destructor_t *dtor;} msg_t` ? This way, the const buffer is directly available in consumer code, but the non-const version would be hidden behind the `p` field? Would this be undefined behaviour?

Comment: @LoPiTaL How do you mean kept in sync? One is just a wrapper aliasing the other, you never allocate two different objects. More intricate solutions are possible by using opaque type and proper private encapsulation. But then you have to rewrite the whole thing to use a better design and no struct members would be exposed at all.

Comment: With sync I mean that if a field is added to the struct, it should be added to both structs, otherwise there may be end up with the fields in different memory positions.

Comment: @LoPiTaL You can make the struct contain another struct with all shared fields.

Comment: See my edit. I think this is what you comment about the "shared fields". My last question remaining, would this be undefined behaviour or is perfectly fine?

Comment: @LoPiTaL It's well-defined but sloppy design, since the caller will have access to both alternatives.