# Assigning values to constant member of dynamically allocated struct during initialization

Tags: c, pointers

I have a point struct:

```
struct Point 
{
    const int x; 
    const int y;
};
```

In my code I have many of these points so I'd like to create pointers to them so I don't see them copied over and over while I work on them.

Knowing that you can initialize constant members of structs like so:

```
struct Point my_point = { .x = 1, .y = 2};
```

I thought I could do the same with dynamically allocated structures. But it doesn't appear to be the case:

```
struct Point *point = malloc(sizeof(struct Point));

*point = (struct Point){.x = 1, .y = 2};
```

However I get

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:23:8: error: assignment of read-only location ‘*point’
 *point = (struct Point){.x = 1, .y = 2};
```

When using GCC 7.1.1. On clang I get

```
prog.c:23:8: error: cannot assign to lvalue with const-qualified data member 'x'
*point = (struct Point){.x = 1, .y = 2}; 
~~~~~~ ^
prog.c:14:15: note: data member 'x' declared const here
    const int x; 
    ~~~~~~~~~~^
prog.c:15:15: note: data member 'y' declared const here
    const int y;
    ~~~~~~~~~~^
1 error generated.
```

Is there a method to do this?

example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Point 
{
    const int x; 
    const int y;
};


int main()
{
    struct Point *point = malloc(sizeof(struct Point));

    *point = (struct Point){.x = 1, .y = 2}; 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why do `x` and `y` need to be readonly?

Comment: @JHBonarius Just convenience. I'd like to signal to someone looking at it that these values are not expected to change (they are loaded from a file so it would make no sense to change them in my application anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot really see a good way around this. In C++ you would have solved this with constructors and private members.

But you can use `memcpy`, [which is safe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9691556/6699433):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Point {
    const int x; 
    const int y;
};

int main(void){
    struct Point *p = malloc(sizeof *p);
    memcpy(p, &(struct Point) {.x=1, .y=2 }, sizeof *p);

    printf("%d %d\n", (*p).x, (*p).y);
}
```

It's possible to use variables for this:

```
int x=1; int y=2;
memcpy(p, &(struct Point) {.x=x, .y=y }, sizeof *p);
```

If you're using `gcc`, you could use a compiler extension:

```
memcpy(p, &(typeof(*p)) {.x=1, .y=2 }, sizeof *p);
```

But I do expect that the following would be a better approach in most situations:

```
struct Point 
{
    int x; // Remove const here
    int y;
};

int main(void) 
{
    // Allocate and assign a non const object
    struct Point *tmp_ptr = malloc(sizeof *tmp_ptr);
    *tmp_ptr = (struct Point) {.x=1, .y=2};

    // Create a new const pointer
    const struct Point *p = tmp_ptr;

    // This will invoke compiler error
    (*p).x = 42;
}
```

Comment: Not sure if memcpy give well-defined behavior. I think it will make the "effective type" of what's stored in memory non-const and possibly cause UB hiccups. I'd have to double-check all the language lawyer stuff about effective type in the standard to be sure.

Comment: @Lundin Please do

Comment: @Lundin You can write your findings here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64098563/6699433

Comment: @Lundin Actually, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691404/how-to-initialize-const-in-a-struct-in-c-with-malloc) seems like a good dup for both this and my question

Comment: Posted an answer there. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64100088/584518. I believe the accepted answer is correct but it didn't get that deep into the dirty details.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to const-qualify the struct as whole, not individual members. You can wrap the allocation and initialization inside a "constructor", which returns a read-only pointer:

```
typedef struct
{
  int x; 
  int y;
} point_t;

const point_t* point_create (void)
{
  point_t* obj = malloc(sizeof *obj);
  if(obj == NULL)
    return NULL;
  
  *obj = (point_t){.x = 1, .y = 2};
  return obj;
}
```