# Is it safe to use memcpy on struct with const members?

Tags: c, struct, constants, undefined-behavior

Assume this struct:

```
struct my_struct {
    const int x;
    const int y;
};
```

Is this code safe?

```
struct my_struct *s = malloc(sizeof *s); // Assuming it succeeds

memcpy(s, &(struct my_struct) {.x = 4, .y=6}, sizeof *s);
```

I printed the content of the fields, and they have the desired values. And I compiled with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` and I did not get any warnings. But I'm worried this might be undefined behavior or something. Is this safe to do?

Comment: You are `memcpy` to memory allocated with `malloc` - sure it's safe.

Comment: Safe or not, I respectfully submit that it isn't very readable.

Comment: This is a fairly reasonable way to [assign values to this fields](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9691404/69809).

Comment: @KevinBoone True. Well I could have declared a temporary object to improve readability, but that's not the topic.